# In FreeMarker adding one hour to current timestamp

Tags: freemarker

In FreeMarker, I am trying to add one hour to a timestamp which is in the format "2016-08-11T20:06+06:00".

I have tried and searched on Google, but didn't find way to add hours to the current timestamp. The new timestamp should be current system timestamp plus one hour.

I am getting the following error.

> For "." left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a date_or_time_or_datetime (wrapper: f.t.SimpleDate):
>       ==> current  [in nameless template at line 2, column 19]
>       FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
>           - Failed at: #assign newDate = current.add(10, 1)  [in nameless template at line 2, column 1]

```
<#assign current= .now> <#assign newDate= current.add(10,1) > ${newDate}
```

I have tried this but getting above error. Please help me out.

Comment: <#assign current= .now>
<#assign newDate= current.add(10,1) >
${newDate}  I have tried this but getting above error. Please help me out.

Comment: I can only answer here as this is "on hold" for some reason. So, FreeMarker doesn't support date arithmetic, and generally you should pass the complete dates to the template. But, there's a hack in this case: `(.now?long + 3600000)?number_to_datetime`.